# C#7 'in' parameters allowed with operator overloading

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, value-type

The recent additions to **C# 7** are great and now in the latest release we can pass `ValueType` (`struct`) instances to functions by-reference (*'by-ref'*) more efficiently by using the new `in` keyword.

Using either `in` or `ref` in the method declaration means that you avoid the extra 'memory-blt' copy of the entire `struct` which is normally required in order to preserve by-value semantics. With `in`, you get this benefit (passing a pointer to the source `ValueType` itself), but unlike `ref`, the callee won't be allowed to modify that target (enforcement by the compiler).

In addition to improving the rigor of design intent, `in` has an added benefit over `ref` that the call-site syntax is more relaxed than with `ref`. In fact, you don't need to mention the `in` keyword at the call-site; it's optional.

Anyway, I noticed that apparently you can define C# ***operator overloads*** using `in`-attributed arguments.

```
public static bool operator ==(in FILE_ID_INFO x, in FILE_ID_INFO y) => eq(in x, in y);
//       works:            -----^            -----^
```

This is great if the *by-ref* semantics ***actually do prevail*** in the runtime behavior. But I would find that surprising, because even though **C#** lets you omit the `in` keyword in method calls, the generated code at the call site ***does*** need to be different. Namely, it needs to emit (e.g.) `OpCodes.Ldflda` instead of `OpCodes.Ldfld`, and so forth.

And then there's also the fact that operator overloads don't have a traditional method "call site" that could be decorated with the (albeit, optional) `in` keyword:

```
var fid1 = default(FILE_ID_INFO);
var fid2 = default(FILE_ID_INFO);

bool q =    fid1 ==    fid2;
//       ^--- in? ---^
```

So, does anyone know if the compiler, JIT, and runtime will honor what the code seems to be allowed to express, such that calls to operator overloads with `in`-parameters will actually obtain *by-ref* semantics? I couldn't find any mention of the situation in the docs. Since the code shown above basically continues to work as it did without the `in` markings, I suppose the alternative would be that the `in` keyword is just silently ignored here?

Comment: Operator overloads are no different from other method calls.

Comment: The question seems to be asking "does the compiler generate correct code when calling a static method that happens to be an overloaded operator?"  Yes, it does.  Is that the question that you're asking here?

Comment: @SLaks Ok, but what I didn't mention that perhaps fueled my confusion was that you ***can't*** do this with *interface implementations*... and those are, at least in some sense, "no different from other method calls" too (as you say). The only difference is the promiscuity of the contracts; what you're suggesting is that since, unlike an interface, there can be no arbitrary or foreign '3rd-party' callers for operator overloads, the latter can be allowed. But any exception or edge case would summarily block the whole pemise so it doesn't seem that clear-cut to me.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying.  Interface implementations must exactly match their interfaces so that calls made through the interface can work.  Whereas operator overloading is just syntactic sugar and has no such contract.

Comment: `there can be no arbitrary or foreign '3rd-party' callers for operator overloads` Huh?

Comment: @SLaks Well I guess that's the crux; I think my insight here is that, unlike interface implementations, there's no way for an operator overload of `MyClass` to get called without the caller specifically building **against my class library**, at which point the *by-ref* semantics are plain to see..I guess I was thinking that operator overloads were somehow more strictly mediated by the runtime, and I think this mistaken idea came from the conflation of all the myriad ways `Equals` can happen.

Comment: @GlennSlayden: Operator overloads are static methods. There's no way to *statically call* a *static method* on a particular type without the compiler having knowledge of that type; that's what "static" means; it means that *static analysis* was used to determine the exact method being called.  It is an unfortunate name, since the mechanisms used by the compiler to resolve the method are best thought of as implementation details, but we're stuck with it now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: The compiler does the right thing. Trust the compiler.

Long answer:

An overloaded operator is simply a syntactic sugar for a static method. An invocation of an overloaded operator is simply a syntactic sugar for an invocation of that method.

That is,

```
public static bool operator ==(S s1, S s2) { ... }
```

is just a syntactic sugar for something like

```
public static bool op_Equality(S s1, S s2) { ... }
```

and

```
if (s1 == s2)
```

is just a syntactic sugar for

```
if (S.op_Equality(s1, s2))
```

So whatever behaviour holds for `in` annotations on normal static methods and normal static method calls also holds for static methods which are operators, and static method invocations which are expressions that use those operators.

Comment: @GlennSlayden: I cannot for the life of me understand your follow-up question. Can you give a clarifying example? Or, if it is complicated, maybe start a new question.

Comment: Yeah no, that comment was right before I realized that the runtime is not mediating this stuff at all, and it was confusing because it's stated as a rhetorical question that's actually completely wrong. I'll delete it later. Meanwhile, I think I got it now (as my comment "Well I guess..." above explains)... I was wrongly thinking that the runtime was peripherally involved in shunting callers between the various ways `Equals` can happen... and mistakenly included `==` as part of that. Instead, however, the runtime will *never* call a user-defined `==` of its own accord (right?)

Comment: @GlennSlayden: A user-defined `==` is simply a static method called `op_Equality`.  The runtime sees it as a static method called `op_Equality`.  If a compiler generates a call to such a method, then such a method is called. Does that answer your question? Because I'm still not understanding it.

Comment: @GlennSlayden: What I'm saying in my answer is: imagine every time you see a user-defined `op ==` declared, that the compiler rewrote your code to be a declaration of an otherwise-identical static method called `op_Equality`, and that everywhere a user-defined operator `==` is used, that the compiler replaces it with a call to that method. The runtime doesn't know anything about the semantics of the C# `==` operator; how could it?

Comment: Thinking further, here's the real point: If I write `o1 == o2` where those variables are `Object`-typed, and then at runtime the actual instances are `MyClass`, there's ***no way*** my operator overload will be called, correct?. This type of putative runtime meddling, if it were real, *would* require that the contract for overloaded operators be stronger, and this thought is what motivated the question.

Comment: @GlennSlayden: If you compare two `Objects` using `==` then the compiler generates a reference equality check; the C# specification is extremely clear on this point. I note that if you do something like `object == string` you will get a warning noting that you're getting reference equality, not string value equality, even if the object is a string.

Comment: @GlennSlayden: Now, if you write `d1 == d2` where d1 and d2 are `dynamic`, then the compiler starts again at runtime and does the analysis *as if the runtime types of d1 and d2 were the compile-time types*, and can *dynamically* generate a call to the static method. I honestly don't know how that will work with `in` methods, but my guess would be that the dynamic runtime code generator will do the appropriate unboxing if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, your comment about the significance of these functions being `static` helped a lot.

Comment: @GlennSlayden: I note that C# does *not* make `dynamic` play nicely with `ref`. If we have `static void M(ref P p) { }` and `dynamic p = new P(); M(ref p);`, that's a compile-time error.  If we have `void M(ref P p){}` and `p.M(ref p)`, that's a run-time error. In both cases we can solve the problem by making `M` take a `ref object`. Whether C# makes `dynamic` play nicely with `in` I do not know; I haven't followed the design process that closely.

Comment: @GlennSlayden: If it turns out that `dynamic` does not work with `in`, I would be happy to say "who cares?"  `in` is intended to solve a performance problem, and if you're using `dynamic`, you are plainly someone who is willing to sacrifice both performance and type safety; if your program crashes as a result I would be happy to say that's on you; when you turn off a safety system, the safety system is off.